# Joining a meeting with Zoom meeting SDK sample app Android (Error 5003)

Tags: android, zoom-sdk, zoom-meeting

I'm trying to integrate Android meeting SDK into Android App. I did following steps.

1. Downloaded the "Zoom Android SDK" (zoom-sdk-android-5.14.5.13410) -latest SDK
   [Using this link](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/android/get-started/install-sdk/)
2. Changed the configs with our zoom account details. (App_key, App_secret, Domain)

```
   public void initSDK(Context context, InitAuthSDKCallbackcallback) 
   {
      if (!mZoomSDK.isInitialized()) {
         mInitAuthSDKCallback = callback;

          ZoomSDKInitParams initParams = new ZoomSDKInitParams();
    //  initParams.jwtToken = SDK_JWTTOKEN;
          initParams.appKey = "My key here";
          initParams.appSecret = "My secret here";
          initParams.enableLog = true;
          initParams.enableGenerateDump =true;
          initParams.logSize = 5;
          initParams.domain=AuthConstants.WEB_DOMAIN;
          initParams.videoRawDataMemoryMode = 
          ZoomSDKRawDataMemoryMode.ZoomSDKRawDataMemoryModeStack;
          mZoomSDK.initialize(context, this, initParams);
       }
    }
```

3. Then it is running and SDK is initializing as expected.
4. Then in the home screen, clicked the "API user" as explained in the documentation.
5. After loading the meeting screen, entered the newly created "meeting ID" and "passcode" with the generated "zak token".
6. Then after few minutes, it will display the following error message "Make sure you are connected to the internet and your connection to zoom is not blocked by a firewall or proxy. (Error 5003)".
7. Then I downloaded the (zoom-sdk-android-5.14.2.13167) SDK and tried. But same result received.
8. I can join the same meeting with the default Zoom app successfully.

Used environment:

1. App was run on Xiaomi POCO X3 Pro and Huawei Nova 2i devices.
2. Checked with both WIFI and Mobile Data (4G) (All the other apps can consume internet in both devices.)

Please help me to find the solution for this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.